# Concrete mix too much Sand?

Tags: concrete, fence

Hi Knowledgeable people,

I've just dug up old fence concrete bases etc as fence blew down. Re done concrete bases, put posts up etc.

And now I am looking at the concrete and am worried I've added too much SAND! Panic!!

I looked up the ratio online: aggregate, sand, cement, 4, 2 ,1 I think and bought ballast, sand and cement.

I followed the ratio, with 4 ballast, 2 sand, 1 cement etc. However, I'm worried that the ballast having various size clippings in down to sand, meant I didnt need to add the sand?

Will my concrete last?

Answer (score 4):

Fence-post bedding is a non-challenging job and on that basis, don't stress about it too much.

Your mixture sounds perfectly good - the usual place folks go wrong is adding too much water, but see the first sentence of this answer.

Comment: I agree you could have used 100% sand and it would work , I have seen beach sand used in coastal areas with no rock. I have always used 3,2,1 or get a concrete mix then 5-1 . But fence post are contained by the hole not like a slab, I have a friend that has plastic molds and makes bird baths and “yard art”  with mostly sand.